# Eclipse Freezes when writing '.' in a query? (BIRT Report Designer)

Tags: sql, eclipse, birt

I'm using Eclipse for BIRT Reports. When I edit a data set and work on a query, every time I press '.' for example to access table.field, the window freezes for a good 3 minutes. I have no idea what it is doing but it is very inconvenient. Is there a way to disable this type of behavior?

Using BIRT 4.2 on Eclipse JUNO.

Thanks

Comment: i tihk it is trying to be helpful and doing a look ahead for all possible methods in the 'class' preceding the '.'

Comment: It sounds like it is trying to run a query in the background and offer you suggestions for what fields to offer up?

Comment: The problem is it is a big query and takes a good 3-4 mins to query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you could disable this behavior by disabling the auto activation of a 'Content Assist' specific to BIRT Report Designer.

I have not used that specific flavor of eclipse so would not be able to advise on specifically which Content Assist to disable. However, it might be worth going into Eclipse Preferences (Window -> Preferences) and searching for 'Content Assist'.

For example if I had to disable the content assist inside Java classes I could un-check 'Enable Auto Activation', like so :

[image]

Comment: Window->Preferences->Report Design->Data Set Editor->JDBC Data Set did it, thanks